# measure the process lifetime (since it was loaded into memory)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, process

Is there any attribute of a process that shows its lifetime (since it was loaded into memory)

and what are the WINAPI used to extract this information?

I want to be able to measure the lifetime of any process in the system

Comment: You could save the current time in your WinMain function and calculate the difference if you want to know the lifetime.

Comment: I mean any process in the system, not mine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're after the [`GetProcessTimes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. You provide a handle to a process (you may need to have the appropriate security attributes), and also provide several pointers to `FILETIME` structs, which you can translate into `SYSTEMTIME` with [`FileTimeToSystemTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). One of the `FILETIME` objects refers to the process's creation time, which is probably the closest you will get to when the executable was loaded into memory.

Comment: Ya, I could use the creationTime output of this function, thanks a lot